# Why am I experiencing a crash in cellForRowAtindexpath?

Tags: iphone, ios

I had uploaded my app to the App Store but it was rejected two times, with the reason being that the app is crashing on iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3.5). I have tested my app on the same version but I can't make it crash.

My app is getting user location for drawing a path on g-map. I have also tested with location service enable/disable, wifi on/of. For all these ways I have tested, my app is not crashing.
After symbolicating my last crash report I have found location and that is in `cellForRowAtindexpath`:

```
if([finalarray count]>0)
{
    cell.shopnamelbl.text=[[finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.distancelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@km",[[finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"distance"]];
}

else if([unsortedarray count]>0)
{

    cell.shopnamelbl.text=[[unsortedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.distancelbl.text=@"";      
}
else 
{
    cell.shopnamelbl.text=@"Loading...";
    cell.distancelbl.text=@"";
}

return cell;
```

in above code on `cell.shopnamelbl.text=@"Loading...";` this line is the cause of my crash, but in my testing everything works perfectly.  I am not seeing a crash anywhere else in my app.

So now what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you releasing shopnamelbl and other properties which you might have defined in your custom table view cell ? any way apple do not allow you display any alert kind of message like 'Loading..' or 'Wait..' on other control. Use UIAlerView to display such kind of message.**(but still i am not sure that may be cause)**

Comment: Apple will provide you with a crash report, symbolize this report and it will tell you where it crashed.

Comment: thanx and Yes,i have done the all the procedure of symbolize after that i have find the location but that is not reason for crash.

Comment: i didn't release shopnamelbl and distancelbl so, was it reason for app crash?

Comment: @Control-V - That's not correct.  You certainly can indicate loading status within a control (in fact, it's encouraged if it can be done so in a way that doesn't block the interface).  UIAlertViews should be used for errors and failures, not progress updates, because of their style and because they block the user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted, so it's likely to be some other difference between what you've been testing and what Apple have on their handsets.

On first run, their device will have nothing in `NSUserDefaults` set, nothing in the keychain, nothing in the Documents directory. You need to completely wipe your device of any trace of previous runs of your app. Deleting and re-installing isn't enough.

It might also be worth trying on a number of devices. It's possible that you've inadvertently made some assumptions about how long certain operations take which don't hold on the faster/slower/different handsets that Apple uses for testing.